# Can't get data from ajaxed clicked element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have AJAX code that adds rows to a table. Each row contains a club member  name, and an email envelope icon.  The goal is to click on the the envelope icon a page for sending email.

Here's guts of the ajaxed rows:  (mno is the member number)

```
function show_names(fullname,key){
$('#results_table').append(
'<tr class="table_row" >
<td>' + fullname + '</td>
<td><img src="/images/email_envelope.png" alt="Send Email" style="cursor:pointer" class="envelope" data="' + mno + ' "/></td>
</tr>');
```

Here are two examples of jquery I tried, nether of which work:

```
$('.envelope').on('click',function(){
document.location="email1.php?mno="+$(this).attr("data");
return false;
});
```

The above results in nothing happening after the click event.

```
$('#results_table').on('click',$('.envelope'),function(){
   document.location="email1.php?mno="+$('click'.target).attr('data');
   return false;
});
```

The above moves to the appropriate page but on arrival mno is undefined.

I've tried all sorts of other things, but I get either of the above two results with the various combinations I've tried.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Syntax error, it's `$('#results_table').on('click', '.envelope', function(){...`

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just wrap an anchor around the image when you append it, seeing as all it does is redirect anyway

Comment: Thanks, corrected syntax helps somewhat... i.e., now goes to the correct page, but with mno= to the 1st item in the .envelope class rather than the clicked envelope.

Comment: Anyhow, yes, an anchor around the envelope does the trick.  Sometimes ya get off on a track and don't see the forest for the trees.  Duh.  Thanks.